# Extend Visitor pattern without modifying the original source code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, extensibility

I had a problem to extend Visitor pattern accross multiple modules, you can read explanation of the issue in the comments.

```
interface Example {

    interface ISource {
        Object accept(ISourceVisitor visitor);
    }

    class Module1Source1 implements ISource {
        @Override
        public Object accept(ISourceVisitor visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    class Module1Source2 implements ISource {
        @Override
        public Object accept(ISourceVisitor visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    interface ISourceVisitor {
        Object visit(Module1Source1 wheel);
        Object visit(Module1Source2 engine);
    }

    class SupportedCurrenciesVisitor implements ISourceVisitor {
        @Override
        public Object visit(Module1Source1 wheel) {
            return ImmutableList.of("USD");
        }

        @Override
        public Object visit(Module1Source2 engine) {
            return ImmutableList.of("EUR");
        }
    }

    //suppose we don't want to change the code above because it's in another library
    //I want to add one more source

    class Module2Source1 implements ISource {
        @Override
        public Object accept(ISourceVisitor visitor) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // I cannot change ISourceVisitor, so what do I need to do?
    // one way is to create another interface

    interface IAnotherModuleSource extends ISource {
        Object accept(IThisModuleSourceVisitor visitor);
    }

    interface IThisModuleSourceVisitor extends ISourceVisitor {
        Object visit(Module2Source2 module2Source2);
    }

    class Module2Source2 implements IAnotherModuleSource {
        //it's ok
        @Override
        public Object accept(IThisModuleSourceVisitor visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
        //but what should we do with this:??
        @Override
        public Object accept(ISourceVisitor visitor) {
            return accept((IThisModuleSourceVisitor) visitor);
        }

        //this way if SupportedCurrenciesVisitor will be passed to the Module2Source2 we 
        //will have CCE
        //but it's ok if we pass here specific visitor for this module
    }

}
```

Apparently if we would place the method getSupportedCurrencies() in ISource
there would be no such problem, but it's also not perfect way I suppose.

The question is can we do better with Visitor?

Or what would be your suggested approach in this situation?

Comment: You can use some default action for base visitor: print log entry and/or throw an exception to be handled somewhere else. Why do you suppose there's a better option?

Comment: Because I presume that there is someone smarter than me out there =), I also considered exceptions but we will wait, maybe someone will come up with another idea.

Comment: Well, one option to make code work w/o CCE: `class Module2Source2 extends Module1Source1 implements IAnotherModuleSource`. But I don't know if it's acceptable for you.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but despite Wikipedia's example, Hungarian notation has generally been abandoned in modern high-level languages.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr: The problem that you're describing is a result of trying to apply the pattern to a problem that it is not suited for.

"Reasons to change" all fall into 2 basic categories: data and functionality.  The visitor pattern decouples the normal OO direct association between the data and functionality in a way that lets you sacrifice the ability to change the data structure in exchange for being able to change functionality very easily.  It would be trivial to add another `ISourceVisitor` because that's what the Visitor pattern is designed to let you do.  Adding another `ISource` changes your data structure and forces you to change all of your functionality to accommodate it, which is a sure sign that you picked the wrong pattern.